# TS error when passing in prop of type React.Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the following component I have a prop of type React.component

```
interface IDemoProps {
  Header: React.Component;
}

export class DemoApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <header>{this.props.Header}</header>
    }
}
```

When I try to pass in a component to this prop, like so:

```
const MyHeader = () => {
    return <div>
                <h1>My header!!!</h1>
            </div>
}

<DemoApp Header={MyHeader} />
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[ts] Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'Component<{}, {}, any>'.
  Property 'setState' is missing in type 'Element'.
```

I've also tried the following:

```
class MyHeader extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return <h1>Directory Header</h1>
    }
}

<DemoApp Header={<MyHeader />} />
```

With the same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have pass your props/state interfaces to the component when you declare it:

```
export class DemoApp extends React.Component<IDemoProps, {}>
```

First one is props, second is state (which can be an empty object, or sometimes people use `any` if your TS linter allows that).

Secondly, for your functional stateless component, you should type it as such:

```
const MyHeader: React.SFC<{MyHeaderProps}> = (props) => {
```

Where you pass in the props interface as well. Your header component currently doesn't have props so you don't need `MyHeaderProps` yet, but you should still declare it as a `React.SFC`.

This means you'll have to change your `IDemoProps` interface to

```
Header: React.SFC;
```